# How to optimize call center call times?

Tags: optimization, circular-statistics, operations-research

I have been asked to develop a predictive model to optimize call times from a call center. We have historical data on successful calls, date/time, member-specific attributes, etc.

Ideally, the output would be an hour of day and day of week to call a member to have the best chance of reaching them based on the members attributes. I would like recommendations on the type of model to apply and an appropriate method for evaluating the model. Also, any suggestions on potential features to employ would be helpful.

My current idea is to cluster the data points and find the best time to reach people within the cluster by getting the maximal value of a 2d histogram of day of the week and hour of the day.

Basically, I'm trying to maximize P(pick up | member attributes AND hour of day AND day of week)

Comment: Your clustering idea sounds like a really natural strategy. Do you have any past data on _unsuccessful_ calls? Also, do you have constraints to the effect of "don't schedule all the calls at once"?

Comment: I do have past data on unsuccessful calls. There is a column with call outcome (e.g. complete, no answer). Yes, there is a limit to how many calls can be made in a given time slot, but I planned on applying a greedy approach, where the highest probability individuals would be called first until the call limit is reached based on staffing.